# Verb form of "inception"

Tags: verbs

Just out of curiosity, what is the verb form of *inception*?
My (uneducated) guesses are *incept* and *inceive*.

Comment: [This link](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incept) suggests incept, which is a [word](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incept), whereas *inceive* is not.

Comment: *Incept* would mean to ingest something. Most people would simply use *start* or *begin* as verbs for the noun *inception*.

Comment: "Questions... Morphology? Longevity? Incept dates?"  "Don't know, I don't know such stuff. I just do eyes."

Answer (score 2):

There is none in current use! The verb with the same meaning is "to begin".

From [here](http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/2083074):

> The Latin verbs concipere (http://www.merriam-webster.com/netdict/conceive) and percipere (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perceive) migrated to English. Incipere (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inception) did not.
>
> Very possibly, the anglo-saxon "beginnan" was found to be sufficient and no latin-based borrowing was needed.

"Incept" now primarily means "*to take in; ingest*". However, according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incept), it has an archaic meaning (now out of use) of "to begin".

Comment: Let's coin 'Inceive' here on English.stackoverflow.com.  Not just a helpful site; it's groundbreaking!

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=inception says otherwise. in+cipere :\

Comment: Yeah, "inceive" is a pretty cool word, and it follows the relationship of "conception" to "conceive".

Comment: @Karthik Says otherwise than that? That shows that *incipere* became *inception*, as *concipere* become *conception* and *percipere* became *perception*. However, *incipere* didn't migrate to a verb *inceive*, where the others did - to *conceive* and *perceive*, respectively.

Comment: @Kathick: [incept](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=incept) - to begin.

Comment: The point about etymonline isn't that it doesn't have useful information but that it doesn't claim to represent current language. "*These are histories of words only, not things or ideas. The modern word for something might have replaced old, forgotten words for the same object or concept.*"